# $request->file('logoImg') always null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

basically i've a form that contains a file's input type and when submit the form, all inputs returns his content except the file input.

In most replies in this same forum, i found that i need add the  attribute, i've enable file uploading in php, max_file_size over 512 mb , etc etc and nothing results.

When I check $request->input('logoImg'), retrieve the name of file that I've choosen in the form, but if I change to $request->file('logoImg'), expected any uploadable file object, but returns NULL.

I've lot of crazy whith this and I believe that problem is in the Laravel configuration environment, repeat, I believe.

Here Is My Code.

Here the form code in the xxxx.blade.php file

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route ('socioActualizar', $socio->Id) }}" enctype=”multipart/form-data”>



      <div class="row" style="padding:15px;">


         <!-- Main content for option-->
          <div class="card shadow mb-4" style="width:100%">
            <div class="card-header py-3">
              <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Socio: {!! $socio->Nombre_Apellidos !!}</h6>
              <button type="button"style="background:skyblue; float:right; padding:5px; margin-top:5px;" onclick="location.href = '{{ route('cuotas',$socio->Id) }}'">Ver cuotas</button>
            </div>

          </div>

    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
            <div class="card shadow mb-4" style="width:50%; padding:15px; float:left;">
            <div class="card-header py-3">
              <h7 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Datos Personales</h7>
            </div>
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <label for="Numero_Socio">Número de socio</label>
            <input type="number" name="Numero_Socio" id="Numero_Socio" value="{{ $socio->Numero_Socio }}" disabled style="text-align:right; width:25%; padding:5px;">

            <label for="Nombre_Apellidos">Nombre y Apellidos</label>
            <input type="text" name="Nombre_Apellidos" id="Nombre_Apellidos" value="{{ $socio->Nombre_Apellidos }}" style="text-align:left; width:100%; padding:5px;">

            <label for="DNI">Dni / Nif</label>
            <input type="text" pattern="[0-9A-Za-z]{9}" placeholder="Formato 12345678X" name="DNI" id="DNI" value="{{ $socio->DNI }}" style="text-align:left; width:100%; padding:5px;">

            <label for="Direccion">Dirección</label>
            <textarea name="Direccion" id="Direccion" rows="5" cols="1" style="text-align:left; width:100%; padding:5px;">{{ $socio->Direccion }}</textarea>

            <label for="Poblacion">Población / Municipio</label>
            <input type="text" name="Poblacion" id="Poblacion" value="{{ $socio->Poblacion }}" style="text-align:left; width:100%; padding:5px;">

            <label for="Calle">Provincia</label>
            <input type="text" name="Calle" id="Calle" value="{{ $socio->Calle }}" style="text-align:left; width:100%; padding:5px;">

            <label for="Cp_Provincia" style="width:100%;">Código postal</label>
            <input type="number" name="CP_Provincia" id="CP_Provincia" value="{{ $socio->CP_Provincia }}" style="text-align:left; width:25%; padding:5px;">

            <label for="Correo_Electronico" style="width:100%;">Correo Electrónico</label>
            <input type="email" name="Correo_Electronico" id="Correo_Electronico" value="{{ $socio->Correo_Electronico }}" style="text-align:left; width:100%; padding:5px;">

            <label for="Telefono" style="width:100%;">Teléfono</label>
            <input type="text" name="Telefono" id="Telefono" value="{{ $socio->Telefono }}" style="text-align:left; width:100%; padding:5px;">

            <label for="Fecha_Alta" style="width:100%;">Fecha de alta</label>
            <input type="date" name="Fecha_Alta" id="Fecha_Alta" value="{{ $socio->Fecha_Alta }}" disabled style="text-align:left; width:30%; padding:5px;">

            <label for="Fecha_Baja" style="width:100%;">Fecha de baja</label>
            <input type="date" name="Fecha_Baja" id="Fecha_Baja" value="{{ $socio->Fecha_Baja }}" style="text-align:left; width:30%; padding:5px;">




    </div>

    <div class="card shadow mb-4" style="width:50%; padding:15px; float:left;">
            <div class="card-header py-3">
              <h7 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Datos Profesionales</h7>
            </div>
            <label for="Quien_lo_Presenta">Quién lo presenta</label>
            <input type="text" name="Quien_Lo_Presenta" id="Quien_Lo_Presenta" value="{{ $socio->Quien_Lo_Presenta }}" style="text-align:left; width:100%; padding:5px;">

            <label for="Cargo">Cargo</label>
            <input type="text" name="Cargo" id="Cargo" value="{{ $socio->Cargo }}" style="text-align:left; width:100%; padding:5px;">

            <label for="Ejercito">Ejército</label>
            <input type="text" name="Ejercito" id="Ejercito" value="{{ $socio->Ejercito }}" style="text-align:left; width:100%; padding:5px;">

            <label for="Cuerpo_Servido">Cuerpo Servido</label>
            <input type="text" name="Cuerpo_Servido" id="Cuerpo_Servido" value="{{ $socio->Cuerpo_Servido }}" style="text-align:left; width:100%; padding:5px;">

            <label for="Tercio_Brigada">Tercio Brigada</label>
            <input type="text" name="Tercio_Brigada" id="Tercio_Brigada" value="{{ $socio->Tercio_Brigada }}" style="text-align:left; width:100%; padding:5px;">

            <label for="Bandera">Bandera</label>
            <input type="text" name="Bandera" id="Bandera" value="{{ $socio->Bandera }}" style="text-align:left; width:100%; padding:5px;">

            <label for="Compañia">Compañía</label>
            <input type="text" name="Compañia" id="Compañia" value="{{ $socio->Compañia }}" style="text-align:left; width:100%; padding:5px;">

            <label for="Localidad">Localidad</label>
            <input type="text" name="Localidad" id="Localidad" value="{{ $socio->Localidad }}" style="text-align:left; width:100%; padding:5px;">

            <label for="Provincia">Provincia</label>
            <input type="text" name="Provincia" id="Provincia" value="{{ $socio->Provincia }}" style="text-align:left; width:100%; padding:5px;">

            <label for="Fecha_Ingreso" style="width:100%;">Fecha de ingreso</label>
            <input type="date" name="Fecha_Ingreso" id="Fecha_Ingreso" value="{{ $socio->Fecha_Ingreso }}" style="text-align:left; width:30%; padding:5px;">

            <label for="Fecha_Licencia" style="width:100%;">Fecha de Licencia</label>
            <input type="date" name="Fecha_Licencia" id="Fecha_Licencia" value="{{ $socio->Fecha_Licencia }}" style="text-align:left; width:30%; padding:5px;">


    </div>
       <div class="card shadow mb-4" style="width:30%; padding:15px; float:left;">
           @if ($socio->Imagen == '')
                <img id="avatar" src="../img/soldier.png" style="width:125px; height:125px;">
           @else
                <img id="avatar" src="{{ $socio->Imagen }}" style="width:125px; height:125px;">
           @endif

           <input type="file" name="logoImg" id="Img" style="padding:5px; margin-top:5px;" onchange="showMyImage(this)" >

        </div>

      <div class="card shadow mb-4" style="width:70%; padding:15px; float:left;">

            <label for="Observaciones">Observaciones</label>
            <textarea name="Observaciones" id="Observaciones" rows="8" cols="1" style="text-align:left; width:100%; padding:5px;">{{ $socio->Observaciones }}</textarea>

        </div>



     <!-- Main content for option-->
          <div class="card shadow mb-4" style="width:100%; height:55px;">

           <input type="submit" Value="Guardar Cambios" id="guardar_cambios" style="background:skyblue; position:absolute; right:10px; padding:5px; margin-top:5px;">

          </div>



  </div>
  </form>
```

This is my route web.php file

```
Route::get('/socios', 'SociosController@sociosView')->name('socios');
Route::get('/socio/{id}','SociosController@sociosSelect')->name('socio');
Route::post('/socioActualizar/{id}','SociosController@socioActualizar')-> name('socioActualizar');
Route::get('/cuotas/{id}','CuotasController@verCuotasSocio')->name('cuotas');
```

And finally, code in the controller

```
 public function socioActualizar(Request $request, $id)
{
    $socio = Socio::where('Id',$id)->first();
    $socio->Nombre_Apellidos = $request->input('Nombre_Apellidos');
    $socio->DNI = $request->input('DNI');
    $socio->Direccion = $request->input('Direccion');
    $socio->Calle = $request->input('Calle');
    $socio->Poblacion = $request->input('Poblacion');

    $socio->CP_Provincia = $request->input('CP_Provincia');
    $socio->Telefono = $request->input('Telefono');
    $socio->Correo_Electronico = $request->input('Correo_Electronico');

  //  $socio->Fecha_Alta = $request->input('Fecha_Alta');
    $socio->Fecha_Baja = $request->input('Fecha_Baja');

    $socio->Quien_Lo_Presenta = $request->input('Quien_Lo_Presenta');
    $socio->Cargo = $request->input('Cargo');
    $socio->Ejercito = $request->input('Ejercito');
    $socio->Cuerpo_Servido = $request->input('Cuerpo_Servido');
    $socio->Tercio_Brigada = $request->input('Tercio_Brigada');
    $socio->Bandera = $request->input('Bandera');
    $socio->Compañia = $request->input('Compañia');
    $socio->Localidad = $request->input('Localidad');
    $socio->Provincia = $request->input('Provincia');
    $socio->Fecha_Ingreso = $request->input('Fecha_Ingreso');
    $socio->Fecha_Licencia = $request->input('Fecha_Licencia');
    $socio->Observaciones = $request->input('Observaciones');
    //logica de la subida de imagen en laravel

    //obtenemos el campo file definido en el formulario
    $name = $request->input('logoImg'); // returns name of file selected
    $name = $request->file('logoImg'); // returns null Why??
    $request->logoImg->store('uploads');
    if($request->hasFile('logoImg')){
        $logoImage = $request->file('logoImg');
        $name = $logoImage->getClientOriginalName();
        //indicamos que queremos guardar un nuevo archivo en el disco local
        Storage::disk('local')->put($name,  File::get($logoImage));
    }

    //obtenemos el nombre del archivo
    $socio->Imagen = $name;
    $socio->save();

    return Redirect::to('socios/');
}
```

I've too lost in this apparently easy step, but not works, surely is a little little error, but I can't found it.

Very thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a specific answer to your question but my approach to solving your problem would be to step outside your framework for a second and use plain PHP to debug.

In this instance I would take a look at your `$_FILES` superglobal and establish whether your file is being uploaded correctly.

If you're not getting anything in there then I'd look at your `<form>` and inspector in Chrome to ensure that your file is being sent correctly. I don't know if it's your copy-and-pasting but the quotes on your `enctype` looks suspect.

Comment: $_FILES returns [] (emtpy array), but i'll change the quotes in form attributes and test it....

Comment: YOU'RE GREAT!, This are the problem, the QUOTES, i've changed for simple (') and WORKS PERFECTLY. Oh my god, I still have a lot to learn. Ok PROBLEM SOLVED.

Comment: @MarioRodríguez did **$file = $request->file('photo');** work for you after you fixed the qoutes? Or are you using $_FILES superglobal?

Answer (score 1):

Here I copy the code I use to upload images.
To create a thumbnail and save the image I've used **Intervention Image** a PHP image handling and manipulation library.

Here is explained how to install it:
http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation

```
 if ($request->file('image')){
      $imageFile = $request->file('image');
      $imageName = time() . '.' . 'jpg';  //$imageName = $teaserImageFile->hashName();
      $imageSubdir = "events_teaser";
      $imageWidth = "968";
      $thumbWidth = "310";

     $this->uploadImageOnServer($imageFile, $imageName, $imageSubdir, $imageWidth, $thumbWidth);
      $event->image = $imageName;
           }


// **********************************************************************
    /**
     * Upload image on server
     *
     * @param  $imageFile - the file to upload
     * @param  $imageName - the file name
     * @param  $imageSubdir - the subdir in /storage/app/public/images/..
     * @return none
     */
    function uploadImageOnServer($imageFile, $imageName, $imageSubdir, $imageWidth, $thumbWidth){

        // Create dir if not exist (in /storage/app/public/images/..)
            if(!\Storage::disk('public')->has('images/'.$imageSubdir.'/')){
                \Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory('images/'.$imageSubdir.'/');
            }

            $destinationPath = "app/public/images/".$imageSubdir."/";

            // Resize the image with Intervention - http://image.intervention.io/api/resize
                // -  resize and store the image to a width of 300 and constrain aspect ratio (auto height)
                // - save file as jpg with medium quality
                $image = \Image::make($imageFile->getRealPath())
                                ->resize($imageWidth, null, 
                                    function ($constraint) {
                                        $constraint->aspectRatio();
                                })
                                ->save(storage_path($destinationPath . $imageName), 75); 

            // Create the thumb            
                $image->resize($thumbWidth, null, 
                    function ($constraint) {
                        $constraint->aspectRatio();
                })
                ->save(storage_path($destinationPath . "thumb_".$imageName), 75); 

    }
```